# zip file does not appear in Program Files

Tags: windows-7, zip, 32-bit

I downloaded a zipped program to take care of an USB disk problem, and I decided to unzip it into the Program Files folder. So I cut the zip from my Downloads folder and pasted it into Program Files, where it's nowhere to be seen.

The options for hiding system files is disabled, the one for seeing hidden files is enabled.

If I try pasting the file again, Windows tells me it's already there and asks me if I want to overwrite it, problem is I still can't see it, not even to delete it before unpacking it somewhere else.

What's happening, and how do I remove that file?

Comment: show hidden files to see if it's there. anyway why do you put files in Program Files folder? Only installed programs should be there

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc it is a standalone program, I figured out it was good to put it where the other programs are.

Answer (score 0):

When weird things appen best is to use the windows shell.

ctrl + r, type *cmd* and run as an Administrator.

cd into your directory

```
cd C:\Program Files
```

and delete the lost file

```
del *.zip
```

Comment: O.o Impossibile trovare C:\Program Files\*.zip (for all you non-Italian speakers: file not found)

Comment: Can you dir *.Zip ?

Comment: Yes and it finds nothing.